Getting cursor position in a regular text field
From what I've read, you can use TextFieldValue to get the cursor position in a BasicTextField as described in How to get cursor position for TextField (Jetpack Compose)?.
Is there a way to get the cursor position in a regular TextField? Or is there a workaround?

Jetpack Compose has two TextField composables.
One which accepts String value
    fun TextField(
        value: String,
        onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
        ...
    )

Second one which accepts TextFieldValue value
    fun TextField(
        value: TextFieldValue,
        onValueChange: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
        ...
    )

If you want to get cursor position, you have to use second one which accepts TextFieldValue value. Because, TextFieldValue has selection parameter of type TextRange. You can get cursor position from selection.

selection - the selection range. If the selection is collapsed, it represents cursor location. When selection range is out of bounds, it is constrained with the text length.

We can implement it like this
    var greeting by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            TextFieldValue(
                text = "",
                selection = TextRange.Zero
            )
        )
    }
    
    
    TextField(
        value = greeting,
        onValueChange = {
             greeting = it
        },
    )


    Button(
        onClick = {
            if (greeting.selection.collapsed) {
                Log.d("CursorPosition", greeting.selection.end.toString())
            }
        },
    ) {
        Text("Click me")
    }

You can also use selection.start instead of selection.end, both of them have same value. Because, greeting.selection.collapsed will only be true when both values selection.start and selection.end are equal.
